# Django model building for monitoring system (IoT)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an IoT project with devices that will capture climate data (like weather stations). I am using Django for the server-side functions and data management, and django-rest-framework for communication with the devices. My problem is with building the models. Here are my models.py:

```
class Devices(models.Model):
    deviceid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    devicesecretid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=16)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type + ' - ' + self.deviceid

class DeviceData(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Devices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requestid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    humidity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    rain = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    sunlight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    battery = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    co2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.requestid) + ' - ' + str(self.added)
```

With my existing code I am building 2 tables (please correct if I am wrong), one which will contain all the weather stations (id, secretid, longitude, latitude) and the other one all the data captured by all of them. Let's assume that we have 10,000 working weather stations that will send data every 15 minutes. This will mean that after a year, our tables will look like that:

-Devices: 10,000 rows because there are 10,000 devices

-DeviceData: 350,400,000 rows because there are 10,000 devices sending data every 15 minutes every day of the year (4*24*365*10,000)

What actually bothers me is that there are a lot of rows in the DeviceData. Wouldn't this be a problem. Is there a way to have a table dedicated to the data from every single device. This will create like 10,000 tables. Is it a bad idea? Is there anything better I could do? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Ps I am building it for learning purposes as a project. I am a student and new to Django.

Comment: How, and how often, is the data going to get used post-collection? I can say that 10,000 tables probably isn't the way to go - it will be more difficult to write code against all of those tables and, in my opinion, is not very sound database design.

Comment: It will be used every day for machine learning purposes and of course every time a user requests for it. For example, the user will want to see every day from every weather station the last values (temperature humidity) and may request some graphs on the data-captured from last month for every weather station. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would look at having an archive where you peel off each month's data into its own table, which will yield tables with 29,200,000 rows (at least, that's the upper limit - I have to imagine it will be considerably less when you figure in device failure, etc)...and if these tables are properly indexed and have efficient queries written against them, then performance shouldn't be a huge issue.